# SignatureDoesNotMatch - Amazon s3 can't upload image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

Error:

> Excon::Error::NotFound (Expected(200) <=> Actual(404 Not Found)
>
> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

I have developed uploading images via carrierwave via s3. But this error happens and aws access id and secret key are not wrong. And s3 settings is currently in public.

Development:
Heroku
Rails

Comment: recheck your bucket name,  endpoints, and region (depending upon the way  you are using these parameters for interacting with s3). also check the key you are using for object to be uploaded

Comment: This error can mean only a few things: your signing code has a bug causing it to generate an invalid signature, or you are modifying the request after signing it, or your secret key is incorrect or incomplete.  This is **not** a permissions issue or a problem with roles or policies or the bucket/region/endpoint settings.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'll try to check it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

The region setting was wrong.
After I update, that would work.